# Html parser to dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup

I am struggled trying to convert a html table to a dataframe. I would like to write the table in a csv file.

```
from requests import session
import sys
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


c = session()

outfile = open("Weather2017.csv", 'wb')
response = c.get('http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EGLL/2017/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=31&monthend=12&yearend=2017&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
soup = soup.find(id="obsTable").text.replace('\n','',1)
outfile.write(soup.replace('\n',',London\n'))
```

the type error is the following

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-1e149d844e15> in <module>()
     11 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
     12 soup = soup.find(id="obsTable").text.replace('\n','',1)
---> 13 outfile.write(soup.replace('\n',',London\n'))
     14 
     15 

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

this is the table I want to covert in to a csv file

[image: table image]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to write text to the file then open it as text `open("Weather2017.csv", 'w')`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
from requests import session
import sys
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


c = session()

response = c.get('http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EGLL/2017/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=31&monthend=12&yearend=2017&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find(id="obsTable")

headers = [header.text.encode('utf-8').strip() for header in table.find_all('th')]

rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
  rows.append([val.text.encode('utf-8').strip() for val in row.find_all('td')])

del rows[0] # Remove header row. Added as empty.

with open('Weather2017.csv', 'wb') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(headers)
  writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The things causing a problem in your code when applying BeautifulSoup() are these tags:
tbody , /tbody , thead, /thead. if you get rid of them everything will work well!

Here is a solution using pandas, regex and some other libs :)

```
#needed imports 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as numpy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

# get page html code
url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EGLL/2017/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=31&monthend=12&yearend=2017&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA'
req = requests.get(url)
html = req.text
soup = (BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser'))

#removing tags that cause problems using re library
patterns = ['<tbody>','</tbody>','<thead>','</thead>']

cleaned_html= soup.prettify()
for pat in patterns:
    cleaned_html = re.sub(pat, '', cleaned_html)

df = pd.read_html(cleaned_html, attrs={'id':'obsTable'})[0]

df.head()
```

[image]

```
# build a hierarchical columns
df.columns = [['2017', 
            'Temp. (°C)','Temp. (°C)','Temp. (°C)',
            'Dew Point (°C)','Dew Point (°C)','Dew Point (°C)',
            'Humidity (%)','Humidity (%)','Humidity (%)',
            'Sea Level Press. (hPa)','Sea Level Press. (hPa)','Sea Level Press. (hPa)',
            'Visibility (km)','Visibility (km)','Visibility (km)',
            'Wind (km/h)', 'Wind (km/h)','Wind (km/h)',
            'Precip. (mm)', 'Events'],

            ['Jan',
            'high','avg','low',
            'high','avg','low',
            'high','avg','low',
            'high','avg','low',
            'high','avg','low',
            'high','avg','high',
            'sum',
            'nan']]


df.head()
```

[image]

```
#removing the first un-needed rows
df = df.drop([0,1], axis=0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df.head()
```

[image]

```
#save the result to CSV file
df.to_csv('weather.csv')
```